# How can I efficiently query a table with revisioned values?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I need to store a table of task items where each item has a unique identifier. Tasks can arrive multiple times, the identifier is therefore not a primary key. I do however only care about the latest version of a task which I identify using a sequence. Every instance of a task can be *NEW* or *DONE*. The tables look somewhat like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TASKSEQ;

CREATE TABLE TASKS (
  ID VARCHAR2(100),
  STATE VARCHAR2(50),
  SEQ NUMBER(20)
);
```

As a data simulation, consider that the table contains a million complete tasks but that a new batch of previously existing tasks arrived right after setting the state to `NEW`.

```
BEGIN
  FOR IDX IN 1..1000000
    LOOP
      INSERT INTO TASKS (ID, STATE, SEQ)
      VALUES (IDX, 'DONE', TASKSEQ.NEXTVAL);
    END LOOP;
  FOR IDX IN 900001..1000000
    LOOP
      INSERT INTO TASKS (ID, STATE, SEQ)
      VALUES (IDX, 'NEW', TASKSEQ.NEXTVAL);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

I am now trying to select tasks that are marked as `NEW` in their latest revision. I do not really care about the order in which I process these tasks, just about the fact that those tasks are marked `NEW` in their individual latest revision. I would like to read "old" tasks first to avoid live-locks. I am fetching blocks of tasks of a given batch size.

The select statement looks something like this:

```
SELECT L.ID, L.SEQ
FROM TASKS L
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ID, MAX(SEQ) MAXSEQ
  FROM TASKS
  GROUP BY ID
) R
ON L.ID = R.ID
AND L.SEQ = R.MAXSEQ
WHERE L.STATE = 'NEW'
ORDER BY L.SEQ
FETCH FIRST 100 ROWS ONLY;
```

Once the tasks arrive in the application, they are processed and updated in the database via:

```
UPDATE TASKS
SET STATE = 'DONE'
WHERE ID = ? 
AND SEQ = ?;
```

Once this update is complete, the next batch of tasks is polled. There might have been parallel writes to the table while processing tasks but other then the statements above, no task is ever deleted from the table.

The data in the table would for example be:

```
ID|STATE|SEQ
A |NEW  |1
A |DONE |2
B |DONE |3
B |NEW  |4
C |NEW  |5
C |NEW  |6
```

In this case, I would expect that a polling would contain (B,4) and (C,6) but not A. After updating these tuple states to *DONE*, I would expect that the subsequent poll would not contain any data unless more data was inserted in the table.

I am wondering if this table design can be implemented efficiently with an index and how this index would look like. A simple index such as

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX NEW_TASK_INDEX ON TASKS (ID, SEQ, STATE);
```

does not do the trick do to the ordering constraint and I wonder how I could change or add an index to accomplish my goal. I also wonder if a materialized view would be a better option to define an index onto it.

---

Update: As for the suggested solutions, here are the query plans for executing the statements, when adding

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tasks_idx1 ON tasks (ID ASC, SEQ DESC);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX tasks_idx2 ON tasks (STATE, SEQ);
```

I get the following plan:

[image: Query plan first suggestion]

For the altered select statement, I get the following plan which seems more efficient but runs quite a bit slower then the above selection:

[image]

Comment: Why do you need the sub-query?  Or did you not mean to put in `AND L.SEQ = R.MAXSEQ` in the join?  This query will only return items with state = new and max of sequence number

Comment: I add it to filter the list of tasks to only contain those tasks with the highest sequence number for each individual tasks. For example, if the table contains id "A" with sequences 1,2,3 and "B" with 4,5, I only want A,3 and B,5.

Comment: Before and after data would really help.  I can't figure out what you are doing to the data.  New tasks are coming in.  What happens to the old data for the tasks?  What if there are duplicates in the new tasks?  Is this for a one-time load or are new tasks trickling in all the time?

Comment: I extended the question with some example data.

Comment: create an INDEX only on ID and SEQ and see if it helps

Comment: That seems to help. Can you eleborate why? I was convinced that the additional field in the index would allow to reduce lookups.

Comment: I mentioned it based on the understanding from this article https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/sorting-grouping/indexed-order-by you can also include ID,SEQ ASC in your INDEX

Comment: After following the tip in the answer where I added a dummy column, the performance stumbled again.

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter Did you try the index and the query suggested in the answer?

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter Any improvement with my answer also Please post the explain plan of your query

Comment: any update on the current situation any gain with the latest set of answers

Comment: I am actively working with a solution with currently trying out a detour via materialized views.

Answer (score 3):

## UPDATED 3/22/19 based on this comment

> > Please check whether the query addresses this case from OP "In this case, I would expect that a polling would contain (B,4) and (C,6) but not A"

I would start with this:

#### Setup

(same as yours, but I added a `TASK_DATA` column for more accurate results)

```
CREATE SEQUENCE TASKSEQ;

DROP TABLE TASKS;

CREATE TABLE TASKS (
  ID VARCHAR2(100),
  STATE VARCHAR2(50),
  SEQ NUMBER(20),
  TASK_DATA VARCHAR2(500)
);

BEGIN
  FOR IDX IN 1..1000000
    LOOP
      INSERT INTO TASKS (ID, STATE, SEQ, TASK_DATA)
      VALUES (IDX, 'DONE', TASKSEQ.NEXTVAL, LPAD('.',500,'.'));
    END LOOP;
  FOR IDX IN 900001..1000000
    LOOP
      INSERT INTO TASKS (ID, STATE, SEQ, TASK_DATA)
      VALUES (IDX, 'NEW', TASKSEQ.NEXTVAL, LPAD('.',500,'.'));
    END LOOP;
END;
```

#### Create index on `STATE`,`ID`,`SEQ`

```
CREATE INDEX tasks_n1 ON tasks ( STATE, ID, SEQ );
EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(user,'TASKS');
```

#### Query

```
SELECT l.id, l.seq, l2.task_data FROM
(
SELECT l.rowid row_id, 
       l.id, 
       l.seq, 
       max(l.seq) keep ( dense_rank first order by l.seq desc) 
                  over ( partition by l.id) maxseq
FROM   tasks l
WHERE l.state = 'NEW'
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 'later, completed task for ID'
                 FROM   tasks l3
                 WHERE  l3.id = l.id
                 AND    l3.state = 'DONE'
                 AND    l3.seq > l.seq )
ORDER BY l.seq
) l
INNER JOIN tasks l2 ON l2.rowid = l.row_id
WHERE l.seq = l.maxseq
AND ROWNUM <= 100
;
```

On my system, that query runs with 4,433 buffer gets.  That's not great, but it should run in maybe a few seconds on most systems if it runs often enough that most of the index is in the cache.  Almost all the buffer gets are reading the index.

A few notes:

1) I added a TASK_DATA column to avoid getting results that only seem great because the indexes were covering the whole SELECT list and/or there were an unrealistically high number of rows per block, making full scans seem better than they would be really.

2) This approach runs relatively quickly because the index covers everything needs to satisfy the `l` inline view, so it can do that work by reading just the index.  Sorting the 100,000 rows that `l` will return is pretty fast and small enough to do in memory usually.  Finally, it only bothers to go to the table for the `TASK_DATA` information for the 100 rows you actually want to return.

Comment: Please check whether the query addresses this case from OP "In this case, I would expect that a polling would contain (B,4) and (C,6) but not A"

Comment: @psaraj12 I appreciate the gentle way you worded that, since I'm pretty sure you knew darn well my answer didn't address that case.  )  Anyway, I've updated my answer and I think it's covered better now.  The performance suffered to address it, but I think it is still not so bad.  I'll be interested to see other answers.  If I get time, I'll try to come up with something better later.

Comment: Even I had overlooked it hence I informed you

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts Matthew. The query plan seems quite efficient indeed but running the query still takes about ten seconds what is more then I can afford. The more I think of it, the more I think that a materialized view might be the best way to do this, actually, I would not know how Oracle could read this query directly from an index. I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: HI Rafael in the Explain plan I would check the cost for each operation HASH_JOIN,SORT etc otherwise the Total cost can be quite misleading

Comment: @RafaelWinterhalter Your explain plan indicates you have 10 million rows in your table, not 1 million.  And how many seconds can you "afford"?  There are more aggressive tuning measures.  But, before exploring them, I would suggest you change your application so that, when it updates a task to "DONE", it finds the earlier "NEW" tasks for the same ID and marks them to "DONE" (or "SKIPPED") or something.  Better to add a little overhead to the update process rather than waste computer resources searching through "NEW" records over and over again that you don't really need to process.

Comment: I ran different tests, therefore the divergence. Yes, updating those fields is my backup plan. I was just wondering if I could have avoided it by a clever index but thinking of how the btrees would look like I start to see how this would not work out.

Comment: I think your backup plan should be the primary plan.  Suppose you got a seemingly perfect answer.  It would degrade over time, because every time there was a "DONE" record for a task having earlier "NEW" records, those "NEW" records would have to be read through and ignored every time your query ran (since they would presumably the oldest values for `SEQ` still in status "NEW").  Your query would get slower and slower over time.  It is better to keep the data accurate in line with application rules.  If a "DONE" record makes the others no longer "NEW", then it is best to update them.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this explain plan  you can use below index for the INNER JOIN

```
CREATE INDEX tasks_idx1 ON tasks (ID,SEQ);
```

For your outer query, you can index STATE and SEQ so that index can be used in Explain plan

```
 CREATE INDEX tasks_idx2 ON tasks (STATE,SEQ);
```

Based on the explain plan you provided use the below SQL and see the explain plan

I would utilize the fact there is an index on STATE and SEQ

Note:-I have avoided the FAST FULL SCAN in the explain plan in the below SQL

For example if there are only 1000 rows in NEW state then only those needs to be scanned for the MAX sequence value

```
with STATE1 as (select * from TASKS where state='NEW')
, STATE2 as (select * from tasks where state='DONE')
    SELECT * FROM 
    (
        SELECT L.ID, L.SEQ
    FROM STATE1 L
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT ID, MAX(SEQ) MAXSEQ
      FROM STATE1
      GROUP BY ID
    ) R
    ON L.ID = R.ID
    AND L.SEQ = R.MAXSEQ
    Where NOT EXISTS (Select 1 from STATE2 where L.id=STATE2.ID and L.SEQ < 
    STATE2.SEQ)
    ORDER BY L.SEQ)
    WHERE ROWNUM <=100
```

I did further testing on your data and the following seams to yield maximum benefit

Update:-Removing subquery refactoring doubled the performance (returned results from 1 sec to 1/2 sec)

```
  CREATE INDEX tasks_idx1 ON tasks (state,id,SEQ);


 SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT L.ID, L.SEQ
FROM TASKS L
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ID, MAX(SEQ) MAXSEQ
  FROM TASKS
  WHERE STATE='NEW'
  GROUP BY ID
) R
ON L.ID = R.ID
AND L.SEQ = R.MAXSEQ
Where L.STATE='NEW'
AND NOT EXISTS (Select 1 from TASKS where TASKS.STATE='DONE' AND L.id=TASKS.ID and L.SEQ < 
TASKS.SEQ)
ORDER BY L.SEQ)
WHERE ROWNUM <=100
```

Comment: I added the query plan I got to my question.

Comment: i have edited the answer based on the explain plan you provided

Answer (score 1):

After many performance tests, I conclude that there is no good solution that only uses an index. In the end, Oracle needs to resolve the maximum revision of each id and then filter those revisions in-memory. There is no way to navigate the b*tree of any index to a small result set but there will always be intermediate materialization due to the fact that the index cannot order on an aggregate value.

A solution I found now is based on using materialized views. First, I created a materialized view log for the base table:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON TASKS 
WITH ROWID, SEQUENCE(ID, SEQ) 
INCLUDING NEW VALUES;
```

The I create a helper view that always contains the maximum revision for each id:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LATEST_REVISION
REFRESH FAST ON COMMIT
AS 
SELECT ID, MAX(SEQ) MAXSEQ
FROM TASKS
GROUP BY ID;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX LATEST_REVISION_IDX ON LATEST_REVISION (ID, MAXSEQ);
```

Using this table, I can now create a materialized view that contains the data that I want in an indexable manner:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LOG ON LATEST_REVISION
WITH ROWID, SEQUENCE(ID, MAXSEQ)
INCLUDING NEW VALUES; 

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW LATEST_ENTRIES
REFRESH FORCE ON COMMIT
AS
SELECT T.ID, T.SEQ, T.STATE
FROM TASKS T
INNER JOIN LATEST_REVISION R
ON T.ID = R.ID AND T.SEQ = R.MAXSEQ;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX LATEST_ENTRIES_IDX ON LATEST_ENTRIES (STATE, SEQ);
```

Due to the append-only use of the base table, the refresh force seems to always result in a fast refresh for us giving us millisecond performance at the cost of some disk overhead. This performance is retained even in a table containing a billion task entries.